# How to do something for each child element of Selenium::WebDriver::Element

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm using `selenium-webdriver` to get information from web sites.

Currently I get children elements of current element like this.

```
tr_element.find_elements(:xpath, "./td").each{|td| p td.text }
```

This `tr_element` is a `Selenium::WebDriver::Element`.

Is there a method that enable like `tr_element.children.each{|td| p td.text }`?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see the HTML, and then get an idea of what you're trying to select.

Comment: There is no such method, what you are looking for. You have to use either `xpath` (as you are doing) or `css` to get hose.

Comment: if you have no need for the tr_element you should be able to use css `find_elements(:css,"driver.find_elements(:css,"tr:nth-of-type(i)>td")` which will collect all the td elements under sthe specified `td`

Comment: I'm not on a box to give this a try but have you done tr_element.find_elements()?

Comment: Even if that were possible, I think there is some value in ensuring that you're just looking at the td tags, as opposed to assuming that all tags under the tr tag are td tags with text... unless that's exactly what you're looking to validate.  :)

Comment: tr_element.find_elements(:xpath, ".//") may do it to generically give you all first level child elements without just looking at td tags.

Comment: If my answer ended up being helpful to you, I hope you'll consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make one like so:

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Element
  def children
    self.find_elements(:xpath, "./*")
  end
end
```

This code extends Element class with a method that uses Element.find_elements (which searches for elements using the given element as root node), and then searching for all immediate children of the root node using xpath (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) for an explanation of xpath syntax).

Comment: You could improve your answer for novice users by slightly commenting the code posted, e.g. by explaining the choice of xpath used here. Why would this work specifically?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Does this look more useful?

Comment: Yup. :) It may sound daft but I like to think some extra info like this always helps to get with a solution more quickly.